# What does "your standing around " mean?

Tags: difference

I just found this weird expression while I was looking for the meaning of come along and it is as follows: "Come along, Osmond. No sense in your standing around". I think they are using "standing around" as an open noun derived directly from the phrasal verb. I found it at the COBUILD Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kate's answer is absolutely correct, but this is one of those constructions that even most native speakers fail to use in either conversation or writing.

> No sense in your standing around

would usually be cast as

> No sense in you standing around

but even more common would be a 'my' for 'me' swap

> No sense in my standing around

would almost always be cast as

> No sense in me standing around

…and most natives wouldn't even be aware it was wrong. Many would actually think the first version was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In correct English, the possessive (your) is used with the gerund (standing) when saying something about a person's action.

> They were very glad of his coming.

https://www.grammarflip.com/curriculum/possessive-use-with-gerunds

In informal speech "[There's] no sense in you standing around" might have been used.